# Uploading file (Images/PDF) and also preview uploaded images/PDFusing React

Tags: reactjs, image, pdf, file-upload

I am using specified link
[Uploading File using React](https://therichpost.com/reactjs-multiple-images-upload-with-preview-and-delete/)
for uploading files but it is accepting only images, I have to upload PDF's as well, Also want to preview uploaded files.

Please help me in uploading Images, PDF format and preview the uploaded files.
Please let me know if there are any libraries based on my requirement.

I am new to React.Please help me on this
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Share your component or your input.

Comment: I have shared a link, I using the same. please check.

Comment: Yes, by using the same code how to upload PDF's as well ?

Answer (score 0):

If you pass on accept="image/png, image/jpeg" it limits to images also some more options available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

```js
const App = () => {
  
  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    const files = e.target.files;

    if (files.length) {
      const file = files[0];
      console.log(file)
    }
  };
  return(
      <input
      type="file"
      onChange={handleImageChange}
      // accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
    />
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: How to add PDF, Can i see(Preview) uploaded files using above code ?

Comment: you should use `FileReader();` to reading the file.